# Raspberry Pi 4 Running Ubuntu 20.04 Refuses to Find 20.10 Update - No new release found

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, raspberrypi, 20.10

I'm in the process of attempting to move [20.04](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) to my SSD drive and [part of that process](https://medium.com/xster-tech/move-your-existing-raspberry-pi-4-ubuntu-install-from-sd-card-to-usb-ssd-52e99723f07b) is updating to 20.10. Sounds simple eh! I'm not a Linux person thus far, hence buying the Pi!

I've tried many update guides online and I have everything setup correctly as far as I can tell. I'm setup on the `normal` update channel, not lts. I've gone through the terminal command steps to ensure everything is updated

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade

sudo emacs /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades (correctly set to normal)
```

Whenever I execute `sudo do-relrease-upgrade` it just says `No new release found`.

I've also tried these commands:

```
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt full-upgrade
```

The `autoremove` command seemed to do some housekeeping but didn't fix the issue.  I've switched the channel back to `lts` and rebooted - check, no update. Switch back to `normal`, check, no update.

I'm completely stuck now, even some other threads here seem to have knowledgeable folks baffled so I've no hope.

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

It feels like I'm missing a repo in the package manager config or something but I've no idea where to start to check.

**Update**

`sudo apt update`

Output:

```
sudo apt update
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease [269 kB]
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute-security InRelease          
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute-updates InRelease           
Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports hirsute-backports InRelease         
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [101 kB]    
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease [269 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Ign:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages
Get:10 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en [511 kB]
Get:11 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main Translation-en_GB [493 kB]
Get:12 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 DEP-11 Metadata [469 kB]
Get:13 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [102 kB]
Get:14 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [157 kB]
Get:15 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [15.8 kB]
Get:16 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 c-n-f Metadata [28.9 kB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages [12.9 MB]
Ign:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:35 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:36 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages         
Ign:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages    
Ign:35 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages  
Ign:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:38 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe Translation-en [3,264 B]
Get:39 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe arm64 DEP-11 Metadata [608 B]
Get:40 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [4,031 B]
Get:41 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]
Get:43 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe arm64 c-n-f Metadata [668 B]
Get:44 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/multiverse Translation-en [432 B]
Get:45 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/multiverse arm64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main arm64 Packages [31.5 kB]
Ign:36 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted arm64 Packages
Get:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main arm64 Packages [31.5 kB]
Get:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main arm64 Packages [31.5 kB]
Get:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main arm64 Packages [31.5 kB]
Ign:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages         
Ign:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:35 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:36 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages
Ign:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:35 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:36 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages
Ign:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages    
Ign:35 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages  
Ign:36 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted arm64 Packages
Err:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Ign:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:51 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:35 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:36 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:51 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:51 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:53 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe Translation-en_GB [850 kB]
Ign:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:51 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Get:54 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe Translation-en [5,441 kB]
Ign:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main arm64 Packages
Get:55 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,834 kB]
Ign:51 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Err:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:56 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3,338 kB]
Get:57 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [8,115 kB]
Get:58 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [57.1 kB]
Get:59 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 c-n-f Metadata [268 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Ign:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:51 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages [176 kB]
Ign:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:94 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages
Ign:95 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:96 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:97 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:98 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:94 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages
Ign:95 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:96 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:97 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:98 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:94 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages
Ign:95 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:96 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:97 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:98 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:94 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages
Ign:95 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:96 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:97 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:98 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:94 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages
Ign:95 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted arm64 Packages
Err:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Ign:96 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:97 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:98 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:94 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main arm64 Packages
Ign:95 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/restricted arm64 Packages
Err:96 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Ign:97 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:98 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Fetched 748 kB in 6s (126 kB/s)      
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute-security/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute-updates/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-arm64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-arm64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9
```

Answer (score 1):

Open **Software & Updates** and check these settings...

[image]

[image]

**Update #1:**

Download the 20.10 RPi image [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.10/release/ubuntu-20.10-preinstalled-desktop-arm64+raspi.img.xz)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've checked those settings and ensured they match your screen-shots (they do). Still no updates. Always reports `No new release found`. The one time I really want an OS update, it refuses!

Comment: I've just noticed that `sudo apt update` gets some errors on missing index files. Specifically arm64 package indexes too.

Comment: @Jammer Copy/paste `sudo apt update` output into your question, select the pasted text, then click the {} icon to format it, and then ping me with a comment that starts with @heynnema, and I'll take a look.

Comment: thanks for your help! I've updated the question, seems things are a little muddled. Which is odd as this was a vanilla fresh install of the 64 bit Pi build. Literally untouched post install to doing the update.

Comment: @Jammer You have multiple sources.list files... /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:9. Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/apt`... and `diff /etc/apt/sources.list:8 /etc/apt/sources.list:9`.

Comment: @Jammer In **Software & Updates**, Ubuntu Software tab, what is selected for "Download from:"? What other choices do you see there in the pop-up? What country are you in? UK?

Comment: @Jammer Did you install the RPi images, like http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.10/release/ubuntu-20.10-preinstalled-desktop-arm64+raspi.img.xz

Comment: Slaps forehead. I assumed that the download link on the Pi page would be the most recent. Why isn't it? I'm going to just flash straight to 20.10. Thanks so much for your time on this.

Comment: I think we both missed the obvious. I was actually trying to "upgrade" 21.04 to 20.10 ... not 20.04 ...

Comment: @Jammer I think we had it right the first time. You wanted to go from 20.04 to 20.10, then maybe 20.10 to 21.04. The naming is yy.mm.

Comment: Sure, but when I checked. The download that I had originally installed was 21.04, not 20.04. So I was trying to "update" to 20.10 from 21.04.

Comment: @Jammer I still think that you're confused. Going from *"to 20.10 from 21.04"* is not an upgrade, but rather, a downgrade. Your subject line also says something different. What version do you have installed now? What version do you want to end up with?

Comment: That's why it's in quotes! I was actually attempting downgrading when I was thinking I was upgrading! Silly me!